# C++: using initializer list to do a narrowing conversion

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11, using Visual Studio 2019.

I have a class `Vector2D` with 2 `float`s: `x` and `y`. And I am using a legacy class `RECT` with 4 `long`s: `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`.

There is a function which requires a `Vector2D` as argument:

```cpp
void DrawLine(Vector2D v1, Vector2D v2);
```

I want the following code to compile without giving me the narrowing conversion error (C2398):

```cpp
struct RECT
{
    LONG left;
    LONG top;
    LONG right;
    LONG bottom;
};

struct Vector2D
{
    float x;
    float y;
};
    
void DrawLine(Vector2D v1, Vector2D v2)
{
    // stuff
}
    
...
    
void main(){
    RECT r = { 10, 10, 100, 100 };
    DrawLine({r.left, r.top}, {r.right, r.bottom});
}
```

I have tried adding constructors with a `std::initializer_list<long>` to `Vector2D`, but I still get the C2398 error. Referring to a similar question, initializer lists don't allow narrowing this way.

Any other methods I could try? Losing precision, etc is not an issue for me.
I can do it with:

```cpp
DrawLine({static_cast<float>(r.left), static_cast<float>(r.top)}, {static_cast<float>(r.right), static_cast<float>(r.bottom)});
```

But I am way too lazy to keep on doing this every time, and it clutters up the code.

Comment: Yeah, this is just how it works. You could always write your own conversion function, or a constructor overload.

Answer (score 1):

As @Blindly mentioned in a comment, simply give `Vector2D()` a constructor that takes 2 `LONG`s as input, eg:

```cpp
struct Vector2D
{
    float x;
    float y;

    Vector2D(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    Vector2D(LONG x, LONG y) : x(static_cast<float>(x)), y(static_cast<float>(y)) {}
};
```

Then your call to `DrawLine({r.left, r.top}, {r.right, r.bottom})` will work as expected.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/xLjImc)

Comment: Many thanks for help. I have tried it. The problem is I already have a constructor with floats, and use it often like so with doubles:
DrawLine(G2XVECTOR2(lastX, lastY), G2XVECTOR2(thispos.x, thispos.y)
After adding the contructor(long,long) VS is giving me 
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'G2XVECTOR2
on beforementioned line. It might help if I make a (double, double) constructor

Comment: Don't believe you, show the code you're trying to compile.

Comment: @carloselfietro I literally give you a working demo where `Vector2D` has both `float` and `long` constructors, and it works fine. What is `G2XVECTOR2()` defined as?

Comment: Ok. It works after I also added the (double,double) constructor. Many thanks!

Comment: PS @blindy: Don't immediatly assume people are lying to you if the solution doesn't works immediately, there might be underlying consequences in the code. I am trying to learn from this great forum, and sharing it to the community, I am not trying to contradict you. And I am very greatful for your help! thanks again.

Comment: I'd rather add a template constructor that accepts any arithmetic type. Having two constructors like this prevents you from having *any* implicit conversions.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good Idea, I have tried this succesfully:
template<typename T, typename U>
Vector2D(const T& tx, const U& ty)
 {
  x = static_cast<decltype(x)>(tx);
  y = static_cast<decltype(x)>(ty);
 }

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to an idea from HolyBlackCat I am using the following contructor in Vector2D:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
Vector2D(const T& tx, const U& ty)
{
    x = static_cast<decltype(x)>(tx);
    y = static_cast<decltype(y)>(ty);
}
```

I know it is not the best practice regarding implicit narrowing etc, but it lets the compiler cast from all arithmetic types in only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

> But I am way too lazy to keep on doing this every time

Well what you are doing is implicit narrowing, and losing precision, so without telling the compiler you're okay with it explicitly (through casting) will generate a warning (that you can turn off, but probably shouldn't).

But that's because you're using implicit construction. Nothing is stopping you from adding proper constructors to your vector class, one that takes floats and one that takes longs, and have the explicit conversion in the latter constructor done only once.

Comment: Also stop using `long`. It doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: How would that constructor look like? I have already tried with:
Vector2D::Vector2D(std::initializer_list<long> list)
{
 if (list.size() > 1)
 {
  std::initializer_list<long>::iterator it = list.begin();
  x = static_cast<decltype(x)>(*it++);
  y = static_cast<decltype(y)>(*it);
 }
}

Comment: There's no initializer list here, just two plain arguments `Vector2D(long x, long y) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks blindy, I know what it means, but I have copied it from old WINAPI code which uses it. In my own code I am using the stdint types

Comment: @carloselfietro the Win32 API does not use `long`, it uses `LONG` which is an alias to whatever type the compiler uses for a 32-bit signed integer, which *may* be `long` or `int` or `int32_t` or whatever the compiler needs.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the questin so it says LONG.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the typo wasn't mine, I just quoted it. And [the proper rules of grammar in English](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/quotations/errors) specify that you don't fix typos in quotes.

Comment: @Blindy I fixed your quote after I had fixed the original typo, so they still matched